# Remove hyphens using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code to find and replace words that are longer than one character, containing hyphen and do not contain digits:

```
new Regex(@"\w{2,}\-\D", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace(s, " ")
```

What do I need to change in order to replace only the hyphens in the matching words?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Use Regex.Replace to find and capture matching words and replace them as you want. It should not be difficult if you know regexes.

Comment: I'm new to regex. What is the expression I need?

Comment: I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly - you want to replace by space not the whole group "*longer than one character, containing hyphen and do not contain digits*" - but only hyphen contained in these groups.

For this you actually don't need to change your regex expression as it does its job and finds these groups.

All you need - is another override of [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which takes not replacement string but [MatchEvaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate. This delegate is called on each match and from this delegate you should return either the original matched string or a replacement string you need.

So your code can look like:

```
new Regex(@"\w{2,}\-\D", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .Replace(s, m => m.Groups[0].Value.Replace("-", " "));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, this should help :

```
string input = "12-12 - a-b test-test test3 abc-xyz - plop";
string regex = @"[a-zA-Z]{2,}\-[a-zA-Z]{2,} ";
string replace = "";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, regex, replace));
```

It replaces all words which have more of 1 alphabetic character at left and right of the hyphen by nothing. 
If there is a number at left or right of hyphen, there is no replacement. Same if there is space around the hyphen. It also removes the extra space.

In the sample string above, "test-test " and "abc-xyz " are removed.